# Can't remove deleted user from file permissions by command

Tags: windows, windows-11, ntfs, file-permissions

I have deleted a user from a PC and I have many files with this permission in the permission tab of advanced form of security ->

```
Account Unknown(S-1-5-21-2076865150-1137883396-1755809354-1013) Deny  Full control
```

See here

[image: 1]

When I do it manually with the GUI, this is OK, it works, I can clean and remove this entry, but I have 500 files to process and this can be very tedious.
If I try this command below

```
icacls  C:\test\Admin\*.* /remove:d *S-1-5-21-2076865150-1137883396-1755809354-1013 /t /c
```

Nothing is changed

Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 0 files
When I check with AccessEnum, I can see all these files.

I have tried a powershell script from this place

https://www.alitajran.com/remove-orphaned-sids/
It complains about Get-ADRootDSE that is missing.

How to proceed to remove this entry with a deleted user ?

Comment: Rights granted with `/grant` are removed with `/remove:g`. Explicit deny rights set with `/deny` are removed with `/remove:d`. So try `/remove:g`.

Comment: I have already tried this, all possible sub-options that can have the /remove option, and it does not work either
I have always ->
Successfully processed 0 files

Comment: "How to proceed to remove this entry with a deleted user ?" - Does the user running the command own the file either explicitly or through user group ownership and do they have explicit permissions to modify file either by being explicitly listed in the ACL or through user group ownership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Account Unknown belonged to a removed user account,
you may be able to clean it up using the
[SUBINACL command](https://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html):

```
subinacl /subdirectories "C:\folder\*.*" /cleandeletedsidsfrom=<domain>
```

The option `cleandeletedsidsfrom` is not mandatory.
The poster used this command:

```
subinacl /subdirectories "C:\temp\Admin*.*" /revoke=S-1-5-21-2076865150-1137883396-1755809354-1013
```

Download subinacl via [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190830103837/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23510).

This is a very old utility, but is still recommended and
might continue working for some time yet.

If the Account Unknown was not the result of a removed user account,
this command won't help.

Comment: I read subinacl documentation and come with this command that worked for me

subinacl /subdirectories "C:\temp\Admin\*.*" /revoke=S-1-5-21-2076865150-1137883396-1755809354-1013

With option
/cleandeletedsidsfrom=<domain>
I had errors may be I needed to replace <domain> with something else ?